# Subtracting from multiple CASE statements

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, case

I'm trying to get the net sales from the query below in SQL Server 2008.

We identify a Sale as Type 1 and a Credit as Type 8.

What I'd like to do is get the Sum of the Sales and Subtract the Sum of the Credits to get the NetSales, but I haven't had any luck.

I'm not really sure if I should be using the CASE statement to get the NetSales. I'd like to see the below from the query, or even with just the NetSales showing:

[image: Wanted Result]

And here is the query:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT IM.IM_PROD_CODE, IV.IV_CUKEY, IM.IM_KEY, IM.IM_DESCR,
   SUM(CASE WHEN IV.IV_TYPE = '1' THEN SH.SH_QTY * SH.SH_PRICE END) AS Sales,
 SUM(CASE WHEN IV.IV_TYPE = '8' THEN SH.SH_QTY * PK1.SH.SH_PRICE END) AS Credits

FROM IV INNER JOIN
  SH ON IV_ENTITY_ID = SH.SH_IVENTITY_ID AND IV.IV_NUMBER = SH.SH_IVNUMBER INNER JOIN
   IM ON SH.SH_ITEM = IM.IM_KEY
WHERE 
   (IV.IV_TYPE = 1 OR IV.IV_TYPE = 8) AND (IM.IM_PROD_CODE = 'ESY') AND   (SH.SH_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-11-01 00:00:00', 102))

GROUP BY 
   IV.IV_CUKEY, IM.IM_PROD_CODE, IM.IM_KEY, IM.IM_DESCR, IV.IV_TYPE
HAVING  
   (IM.IM_KEY = 'A-05.000.007.01_LM')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the result of the second SUM to be subtracted from the first SUM. One option would be to do just that:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
  IM.IM_PROD_CODE,
  IV.IV_CUKEY,
  IM.IM_KEY,
  IM.IM_DESCR,
  Sales    = SUM(CASE WHEN IV.IV_TYPE = '1' THEN SH.SH_QTY * SH.SH_PRICE END),
  Credits  = SUM(CASE WHEN IV.IV_TYPE = '8' THEN SH.SH_QTY * PK1.SH.SH_PRICE END),
  NetSales = SUM(CASE WHEN IV.IV_TYPE = '1' THEN SH.SH_QTY * SH.SH_PRICE END)
           - SUM(CASE WHEN IV.IV_TYPE = '8' THEN SH.SH_QTY * PK1.SH.SH_PRICE END)
FROM
  … /* the rest of your query */
```

Yes, you are repeating the SUM expressions, but that is fine, there are only two of them. The [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle applicable to many other languages is less relevant in SQL, where duplication of code can be a perfectly normal way to achieve better performance.

In this case, however, the duplication can be avoided by using a derived table:

```
SELECT
  IM_PROD_CODE,
  IV_CUKEY,
  IM_KEY,
  IM_DESCR,
  Sales,
  Credits,
  NetSales = Sales - Credits
FROM
  (
    … /* the entirety of your current query */
  ) AS derived;
```

I would also like to suggest, if I may, that you be consistent in how you specify your constant literals. What I mean is sometimes in your query you are providing the matched values for `IV.IV_TYPE` as strings (`IV.IV_TYPE = '1'`) and other times as numbers (`IV.IV_TYPE = 1`). You should really choose one way and, of course, it should be the one matching the column's actual type.

Also, the `TOP (100) PERCENT` in your query makes little sense. It looks as though it may be a remnant of an old [technique for intermediate materialisation](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam%5Fmachanic/archive/2006/10/03/exploring-the-secrets-of-intermediate-materialization.aspx), which, however, may no longer be working in your version of SQL Server.

There is also this HAVING filter in your query (`HAVING (IM.IM_KEY = 'A-05.000.007.01_LM')`), which would work more efficiently if you moved the condition to the WHERE clause.

One last note concerns your second CASE expression (the Type 8 one). One of the columns it is referencing is qualified with an alias that is not found in your FROM clause: `PK1.SH.SH_PRICE`. I am assuming that is some kind of a copy-paste error posting your script here but I thought I would let you know so that you could correct it.

Comment: Awesome Thank you for the insight, I made the changes you suggested. I was also messing up because I had IV_TYPE grouped by which was causing issues with the results.